# One-to-many relationship in Multi Index Tables

Tags: table, database

Is there a method for storing one-to-many relationships within a table? Say I had a Player, and the player had multiple Tickets. How could I store multiple ticket primary keys within one player?

Answer (score 2):

Even if you do not directly support one-to-many, you can set up multiple indexes to:

Create a separate player, ticket struct. These become tables. 
Place a player_id in the ticket and create a secondary index using player_id.
You can search for the player's tickets by using both the player_id and the ticket id.

The following links can help.
https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/multi-index-table-tutorial

Comment: Ahh of coarse, I've worked with graph databases for so long that I'm no longer used to the old way of look ups. I realised you could even use the scope to do some tricky "grouping" like actions on tables.

Answer (score 2):

The link below will be really helpful.
There are many concepts and relationships between them.

https://trybe.one/the-ultimate-end-to-end-eos-dapp-tutorial-part-2/

Comment: Why answer twice? You can edit your questions and answers.

Comment: I like the vector implementation, thank you!